# Execute focusout-function after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an focusout function that I want to execute after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#info_container').delegate('input[type="text"]', 'focusout', function () {
            console.log("Hello");
}, 5000);
```

But this don't work. The Hello is printed immediately, not after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is not "when the focusout-event occurs wait 5 seconds and fire the function" but "wait five seconds and bind the function to the focusout-event".

You should move your timeout into the function body:

```
$('#info_container').delegate('input[type="text"]', 'focusout', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("Hello");
    }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Just be aware of the context inside setTimeout callback, `this` would refer to global object (window in browser), not focused out element, using `bind()` would fix it if needed: `setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(this);
    }.bind(this), 5000);`

Comment: @MartinSchneider: Thank u! Why did not my version worked?

Comment: @Bryan Your logic was wrong, you were **binding** focusout event after 5 secs

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, thank you for the further clarification.